# I want to use Spring Data Rest in aws lambda without Spring Boot & tomcat

Tags: spring-data, aws-lambda

How can I use the Spring Data REST feature in AWS Lambda without using the SpringBoot dependencies which has TOMCAT and Other Heavy dependencies with it ?

My objective is to create a CRUD Lambda completely based on JSON (HATEOS - id possible)

but with minimalistic dependencies - so lambda can fire up easily

Comment: "lambda can fire up easily". You're using Java which makes this relatively hard to achieve. You made it even worse by using Spring.

Answer (score 3):

First things first: if you want to have a Lambda function which should start fast, you should not use Java (but depends on your use case). [Here](https://www.bouvet.no/bouvet-deler/comparing-java-and-node.js-on-aws-lambda) is a nice performance comparison between Java and Node.Js on Lambda.

If you still want to use Java and Spring Data REST, you should take a look at [this AWS repository](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-java-container) which provides a basic framework to instantiate Spring within Lambda. Based on that you should be able to add Spring Data REST.

Comment: Thanx @s.hesse this information is useful but you haven't answered the question's answer - whether Data REST of Spring will work without Tomcat/Spring MVC ?